# How do I look up the proper Windows System Error Code to use in my application?

Tags: c#, windows, error-code

I am writing a C# .NET 2.0 application wherein when a message is expected to be received via the `SerialPort`.  If the frame is not received (i.e. times out) or it is determined to be invalid, I need to set an error code using `SetLastError`.  Windows has a plethora of error codes.  Is there a simple tool or reference to help narrow down the proper error code to use?

***ADDITIONAL INFO***

While throwing an exception and handling it higher up the stack is my preference, that is not an option in this case because the application I am updating was not designed to take advantage of such a useful feature.

Comment: Why do you need to call `SetLastError`?

Comment: @SLaks: I want to use `SetLastError` because higher up there is a feature to log errors to a text file, which is better than nothing, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the "good old days" (C and C++), the list of possible Windows errors was defined in winerror.h

**UPDATE:** Link below is dead.  Not sure if the file is still available for download, but all the [Windows System Error Code definitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx) can be found at this link.

This file can be found on [Microsoft's site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819772.aspx) (although it surprises me a little that it is dated as far back as 2003 - might be worth hunting for a more recent version).

But if you're getting (or wanting to set) Win32 error codes, this'll be where the definition is found.

Comment: I realise this is an old question, but here is a current list showing the error hierarchy:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5tckx.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the above didn't work for me, however this worked perfectly for me, pasting the whole code so it can be copy pasted directly in C#

```
public static class WinErrors
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a user friendly string message for a system error code
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="errorCode">System error code</param>
    /// <returns>Error string</returns>
    public static string GetSystemMessage(uint errorCode)
    {
        var exception = new Win32Exception((int)errorCode);
        return exception.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;       // DllImport

public static string GetSystemMessage(int errorCode) {
int capacity = 512;
int FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM = 0x00001000;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(capacity);
FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, IntPtr.Zero, errorCode, 0,
    sb, sb.Capacity, IntPtr.Zero);
int i = sb.Length;
if (i>0 && sb[i - 1] == 10) i--;
if (i>0 && sb[i - 1] == 13) i--;
sb.Length = i;
return sb.ToString();
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern int FormatMessage(int dwFlags, IntPtr lpSource, int dwMessageId,
    int dwLanguageId, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nSize, IntPtr Arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of them all here:

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2347-error-codes-in-windows

Then just do a search for 'Serial' and use whichever one best fits your error

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the MSDN site shows that the error codes go up to 15,999. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381%28VS.85%29.aspx